# using a priority queue

Tags: stack, queue

You are developing the help desk application of a company. Request of issues will be stored to be served on a priority basis. For each issue, the name of the employee and the description will be stored. Make sure to add an integer to save priority. Insert issues and make the lowest priority be at the beginning of the queue. Implement a priority queue using C++ for issues. Create a menu with the options to add a new issue, service the issue with minimum priority number and any other relevant options. Use a priority queue for this.

Comment: Looks like an interesting class assignment. What have you tried so far and what is your specific question?

Comment: I really haven't tried anything since my deadline is at 11:55pm and I had two more questions to do before this.

Comment: Can someone please help me